# Nextjs setting all route paths dynamically

Tags: reactjs, next.js

At work,

we have a folder path like:

```
pages/user/login.js
```

we want to move it to
`http://example.com/login`

but link tags and folder structure should stay the same.
We should still be using

```
<Link href="/user/login">
```

but it should show as http://example.com/login.
And this should be done *without any folder structure* changes!
We can't replace the href's and we can't move the user.js to root directory.

My coworkers are new to nextjs and they reject to switch without this feature. (CTRL+SHIFT+H(Replace all) was too time consuming so we spent 8x3 hours to solve this)

We've tried next.config **redirects** and **rewrites** to no avail.

```
   module.exports = {
      async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: "/login",
            destination: "/user/login",
          },
          {
            source: "/register",
            destination: "/user/register",
          },
        ];
      },
    };
    // not working: <Link href="login"/>
```

Comment: Do you run next.js with `npm run start`? or just statically export the html?

Comment: We ran it by yarn dev

Comment: You can use a cutom component indise _app.js and just use `router.replace()` see https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-morning-w0s3h?file=/pages/_app.js

Answer (score 0):

The `rewrites` are only for the server and don't affect client-side routing.

To provide the same logic to your client-side routing you can add the `as` prop to your `Link`s, which is a decorator for the path that will be shown in the address bar.

```js
<Link href="/user/login" as="/login" />
```

Comment: Well, thats what I suggested. My coworkers insists that they should not be updating "/login" on all project if we need to update it

Comment: I'm afraid that, without any folder structure changes, this is the simplest solution.

Comment: what about this approach? https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-morning-w0s3h?file=/pages/_app.js

Comment: Yeah, that's another possibe way to do it, which doesn't require changes to `Link`. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you. Coworkers are insisting on importing url's from a static file, would this be a good approach? Like import {loginUrl} from "constants/urls"